# How run different versions of node.js in same time?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, nvm

I have installed node v0.8.25 for my cloud9 application and i want develop on node v0.11.2. So can i run cloud9 on v0.8 and run my programs on v0.11.2 on Ubuntu? I used nvm.

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is in your question. Use nvm.

Comment: Nice, but nvm is not give me ability run deffent versions in same time. I must to swith it to use. I need some like node08, node10 executables.

Comment: Sure it does. `nvm run 0.8 something.js`, then `nvm run 0.11 somethingelse.js`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As hobbs said in his comment, [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is the way to go, since it was made specifically for this.

Check out this nice article on how to set it up/use it with different versions: http://codetheory.in/using-node-version-manager-nvm-to-manage-multiple-node-js-versions/

Check rebrec's comment below for instructions on how to use `nvm`

Comment: Thanks for article, but nvm don't solve my main problem - run different node in same time.

Comment: You should add to the solution : to not run `node script.js` but, instead, use `nvm run 4.4.7` script.js` (if this version is not installed, install it using `nvm install v4.4.7`, to get available versions, use `nvm ls-remote`on Linux or `nvm ls remote`on Windows)

Comment: @rebrec You can do it too :)

Comment: @verybadalloc sorry, but, i can edit your Accepted Answer ?

Comment: @rebrec Alright, just noted you don't have the permissions yet. I will make the edit.

Comment: I skimmed over the article linked and didn't find anything about the [`.nvmrc` file](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown#nvmrc). Maybe it's worth adding this to the answer, as it's an easy way to manage each project's node version.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pm2 to manage your application, you can use the `--interpreter` options and specify the path to your Node.js version.

Example: `pm2 index.js --interpreter /usr/bin/node-v4.2.0`

Answer (score 0):

TJ's `n` module is also useful

Install doing `npm install -g n` and use by doing `n install lts` or `n install 8.2.1` for example. List of all commands is available at https://github.com/tj/n

You can do `$(n bin M.m.x)` to obtain the full path binary for node version `M.m.x` as long as you had installed it previously.