# How to write a .nvmrc file which automatically change node version

Tags: node.js, nvm, nvm-windows

Hi I have two projects one in angularjs 4.4.7 and another in angular 6 version. I need to switch between node version for this. I tried using NVM which is working manually. How to handle the version change inside the angularjs program to change the node version when automatically the latest angular page gets loaded. Is there a possible way like that. I went through the #avn also but how to create the .node-version file. Can someone help with any link or correct sample steps

Comment: You said: "change node version automatically... when the latest angular page gets loaded".... mmm. Are you talking about, when the web-browser loads an "angular page", your SO change the node version?.... forget about that, I think you want this: "When I run the build script, my SO needs to change automatically the node version". Am I right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225153/how-run-different-versions-of-node-js-in-same-time  similar to this question for windows.

Answer (score 604):

As @Aditya-M-P has already mentioned you can run the following command inside your projects root directory to generate the `.nvmrc` to set a desired NodeJS version for you project to work properly:

```bash
node -v > .nvmrc
```

It will generate something like this inside your `.nvmrc` file:

```
v10.16.2
```

Also using `10.16.2` without the `v` letter will work just fine.

However, in the official documentation in the [.nvmrc](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#nvmrc) section it never mentions that once you get this file created, the specified node version will be loaded automatically.
So that's not enough, you need to run the command below so that `nvm` can look for the `.nvmrc` file to load the specified version:

```
nvm use
```

Here it is a gif for demoing purpose:
[image]

##### To autoload the specified node version

You need to add something else to your shell configuration depending on what you use `bash` or `zsh`

To get the exact configuration for each of them, please follow the instructions in the corresponding [shell config section](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#deeper-shell-integration).

In my case I'm using `zsh` so I do need to add this at the end of my `.zshrc` file:

```bash
# place this after nvm initialization!
autoload -U add-zsh-hook
load-nvmrc() {
  local node_version="$(nvm version)"
  local nvmrc_path="$(nvm_find_nvmrc)"

  if [ -n "$nvmrc_path" ]; then
    local nvmrc_node_version=$(nvm version "$(cat "${nvmrc_path}")")

    if [ "$nvmrc_node_version" = "N/A" ]; then
      nvm install
    elif [ "$nvmrc_node_version" != "$node_version" ]; then
      nvm use
    fi
  elif [ "$node_version" != "$(nvm version default)" ]; then
    echo "Reverting to nvm default version"
    nvm use default
  fi
}
add-zsh-hook chpwd load-nvmrc
load-nvmrc
```

and here is the image that confirms it works:

[image]

Comment: I've noticed this makes the initialisation of the terminal session to takes slighly more time.

Comment: Has anyone adapt the "script to autoload the specified node version" to bash (Linux specifically)? It would be a great addition to this answer!  @alexventuraio

**PLUS:** If something like this `(Node.js 16.11.30) [user@computer my-project]$` were possible in the terminal (like in a Python venv), then it would be more than perfect! 

Comment: @GwenM exactly. That's why i switched to [fnm](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm): https://danhough.com/blog/nvm-slows-down/

Comment: This is great and it worked for me just fine.   On a Mac M1 with Sonoma.  Using .zshrc.   Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I'm using oh-my-zsh with Powerlevel10k so I using the flag `--silent` with `nvm use` to avoid `[WARNING]: Console output during zsh initialization detected.`

Comment: There's a considerable visible delay when this hook is added

Comment: There is a massive delay when changing folders. Avoid this and go with the fnm answer, no delay there.

Answer (score 41):

Check the [README](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#deeper-shell-integration) from nvm's repo on GitHub. Solutions have been given there.

### Shell Integraton

For **bash**, put the following at the end of your `$HOME/.bashrc`, the shell will change the node version according to the `.nvmrc` file under the dir.

```
find-up () {
    path=$(pwd)
    while [[ "$path" != "" && ! -e "$path/$1" ]]; do
        path=${path%/*}
    done
    echo "$path"
}

cdnvm(){
    cd "$@";
    nvm_path=$(find-up .nvmrc | tr -d '[:space:]')

    # If there are no .nvmrc file, use the default nvm version
    if [[ ! $nvm_path = *[^[:space:]]* ]]; then

        declare default_version;
        default_version=$(nvm version default);

        # If there is no default version, set it to `node`
        # This will use the latest version on your machine
        if [[ $default_version == "N/A" ]]; then
            nvm alias default node;
            default_version=$(nvm version default);
        fi

        # If the current version is not the default version, set it to use the default version
        if [[ $(nvm current) != "$default_version" ]]; then
            nvm use default;
        fi

        elif [[ -s $nvm_path/.nvmrc && -r $nvm_path/.nvmrc ]]; then
        declare nvm_version
        nvm_version=$(<"$nvm_path"/.nvmrc)

        declare locally_resolved_nvm_version
        # `nvm ls` will check all locally-available versions
        # If there are multiple matching versions, take the latest one
        # Remove the `->` and `*` characters and spaces
        # `locally_resolved_nvm_version` will be `N/A` if no local versions are found
        locally_resolved_nvm_version=$(nvm ls --no-colors "$nvm_version" | tail -1 | tr -d '\->*' | tr -d '[:space:]')

        # If it is not already installed, install it
        # `nvm install` will implicitly use the newly-installed version
        if [[ "$locally_resolved_nvm_version" == "N/A" ]]; then
            nvm install "$nvm_version";
        elif [[ $(nvm current) != "$locally_resolved_nvm_version" ]]; then
            nvm use "$nvm_version";
        fi
    fi
}
alias cd='cdnvm'
```

Cause there's no hook support in Bash, the solution above is ugly.

For **zsh**, put this into your `$HOME/.zshrc`

```sh
# place this after nvm initialization!
autoload -U add-zsh-hook
load-nvmrc() {
  local node_version="$(nvm version)"
  local nvmrc_path="$(nvm_find_nvmrc)"

  if [ -n "$nvmrc_path" ]; then
    local nvmrc_node_version=$(nvm version "$(cat "${nvmrc_path}")")

    if [ "$nvmrc_node_version" = "N/A" ]; then
      nvm install
    elif [ "$nvmrc_node_version" != "$node_version" ]; then
      nvm use
    fi
  elif [ "$node_version" != "$(nvm version default)" ]; then
    echo "Reverting to nvm default version"
    nvm use default
  fi
}
add-zsh-hook chpwd load-nvmrc
load-nvmrc
```

### A Better Solution

A better solution is to use [nodenv](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv). I'm not kidding, `nodenv` is very different from nvm, and n.

`nodenv` is a member of the `rbenv` family. These version managers have big advantages over the others.

1. It changes node version without modifying environment variable `PATH` time by time, because it uses **shim executables**. This makes it having a builtin support to **switch node version automatically**.
2. Auto version switch in `nodenv` doesn't have to be hooked on `chpwd` to do periodical check for directory change. The version selection is delayed to when `node` command is executed.
3. The commands in `nodenv` are implemented in scripts. While, commands from `nvm` are implemented in functions, which means all the 4000+ line of code have to be parsed on shell startup and increases the shell init time dramatically. `nodenv` initializes much faster.

References

- [nodenv/nodenv](https://github.com/nodenv/nodenv)

Answer (score 36):

As pointed out in the [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/995#issuecomment-349670827) related to this on the `nvm` repository, you may run the following command in each of your Angular project folders:

```
$ node -v > .nvmrc
```

Note that you need to first switch to the right version of node in each of your projects, *before* running the command above.

**What's happening in the command**:

- `node -v` will out the current version of `node` to `stdout`.
- The `>` symbol will then `redirecting` the output to a file called `.nvmrc` (it will overwrite if something already exists with the same file name).
- Read more bash redirections under the *REDIRECTION* section under the bash man page: https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

When you `cd` into your target directories, `nvm` will now first read the file, and auto-switch to the correct version.

Comment: there's no auto-switch afaics, you still need to run `nvm use` for the file to be read

Comment: if you want to generate the `.nvmrc` file on windows with the current node version, you can use the following command:
`node.exe -v > .nvmrc`

However, do note that `.nvmrc` is currently not supported in nvm-windows
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/388#issuecomment-418513601

Answer (score 7):

After you create the .nvmrc file at the root of your project with the node version you need in that project, something like

```
v12.20.0
```

You should be able to cd into the project folder and run `nvm use`. This will print something like this:

```
Found '/Users/you/myproject/.nvmrc' with version <v12.20.0>
Now using node v12.20.0 (npm v6.14.8)
```

There is no automated way AFAIK, provided out of the box by NVM except by creating a bash script that does this for you which the NVM documentation covers in detail [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#nvmrc)

Answer (score 7):

For something less involved than a shell hook, you could add a `preinstall` or `prebuild` script to your package.json so every time you try to install or build your project uses the correct version defined in your `.nvmrc` file.

Example `.nvmrc` file:

```
18.10.0
```

Example scripts in `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "preinstall": "nvm use",
  "prebuild": "nvm use",
  "build": "tsc"
},
```

I have not tested this yet but plan to add it to my own project soon. I'll report back how it works.

Note: Using the `preinstall` hook is only called when doing `npm install` and not when installing a specific module.

Comment: I get this      "sh: 1: nvm: not found". But in the terminal vnm works

Comment: @JonathanOrrego first make sure nvm is installed: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script
Then try following the troubleshooting tips if you are on mac: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script

Answer (score 3):

"fnm" supports automatic version switching

https://github.com/Schniz/fnm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

To switch between Node versions automatically [`fnm`](https://github.com/Schniz/fnm) may be used as an alternative to `nvm` like:

```
npm i -g fnm
echo 'lts/*' > ./somedir/.nvmrc
cd somedir
```

You will be prompted by FNM to install the version, if not already installed:

```
Can't find an installed Node version matching lts-latest.
Do you want to install it? answer [y/N]: y
```

Once the expected Node version is installed, FNM will `use` it automatically:

```
Installing Node v20.10.0 (arm64)
Using Node for alias lts-latest
```

The Node version in use will change when the current working directory contains a valid [`.nvmrc` config](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm?tab=readme-ov-file#nvmrc) and based on Node version specified in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The highest rated answer works, but it adds 0.2-0.5s of delay per `cd`. I added this to my `.zshrc` and it's practically instant:

```
#change nvm version on cd
cd() {
    builtin cd "$@" && [ -e ".nvmrc" ] && nvm use &> /dev/null
}
```

Everything else can be taken from the main answer.