# Error: Package exports for tslib do not define a valid '.' target

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc, tslib

I literally made no changes to code, and suddenly I woke up to this error one day,

```
backend: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:454
backend:   const e = new Error(`Package exports for '${basePath}' do not define a ` +
backend:             ^
backend: Error: Package exports for '/Users/kumarabhirup/Documents/Repositories/propagateAt/node_modules/tslib' do not define a valid '.' target
backend:     at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:454:13)
backend:     at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:387:16)
backend:     at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:486:20)
backend:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:781:27)
backend:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
backend:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
backend:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
backend:     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kumarabhirup/Documents/Repositories/propagateAt/node_modules/apollo-link/lib/index.js:3:15)
backend:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
backend:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10) {
backend:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
backend: }
backend: [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

[This person from another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278041/an-unhandled-exception-occurred-package-exports-for-e-projectsl-node-modules) changed their node version and it worked for them, I tried it too (v12.x.x -> v15.x.x), didn't work for me.

I also upgraded `typescript`, tried installing `tslib`, did `yarn cache clean`, deleted and reinstalled node_modules, deleted `yarn.lock`, nothing worked.

Please help.

Here's my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "dist/src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.release.json",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch -p tsconfig.release.json",
    "start": "npm run build && node --experimental-modules --experimental-json-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node dist/src/index.js",
    "start:pm2": "NODE_ENV=production pm2 start dist/src/index.js --node-args=\"--max_old_space_size=500 --experimental-modules --experimental-json-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node\"",
    "dev": "npm run build && concurrently --raw \"nodemon --experimental-modules --experimental-json-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node dist/src/index.js\" \"npm run build:watch\"",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx,ts,tsx",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix --ext js,jsx,ts,tsx",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --passWithNoTests --watch",
    "test:ci": "NODE_ENV=test jest --passWithNoTests"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bull": "^3.14.0",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.5.43",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.3",
    "@types/node-cron": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript-prettier": "^2.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "pm2": "^4.4.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^3.7.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "tslib": "^2.0.3",
    ...
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12.x"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "graphql": "14.x"
  }
}
```

Here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    // "lib": ["es2017"],
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "__tests__/**/*"],
  "paths": {
    "tslib" : ["node_modules/tslib/tslib.d.ts"]
  },
}
```

Here's my `tsconfig.release.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "removeComments": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I workarounded by **downgrading node version** (from v13.0.1 to v12.19.0). It's probably not the ideal solution, but it can help you to unblock the situation while looking for the final fix.

I used **[nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)** to manage node versions.

I leave you an screenshot of problem & resolution.

[image: "'tslib' do not define a valid '.' target" workaround]

I hope it helps to sort out your issue.

Regards!

Comment: I tried downgrading on v12.19.0, unfortunately, it didn't work for me. But it worked for me on v12.18.0. Thanks for the solution! This answer helped me solve the issue!

Comment: I had the same issue, upgraded to node latest using `$ nvm install --lts` and `nvm use --lts`, which was v14.xxx, and it works!

Answer (score 7):

For me, these steps did the trick:

1. Downgrading to latest `NodeJS` stable version: `nvm install --lts`
2. Deleting `/node_modules` & `package-lock.json` files
3. Kill the pm2 processes and add again: `pm2 kill` and `pm2 start process.json`

The trick was actually killing pm2 and adding the process again.
Good luck!

Comment: Similar to yourself, a different version of Node and reinstalling Node modules did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

All of the aforementioned suggestions are correct. Most of the case I run into this error it is due to inconsistent `nodejs` versions.

1. I use `nvm` to manage `nodejs` versions
2. Every project has `.nvmrc` which states a different node version
3. When running the `npm` command on a project running a different `nodejs` version, that command fails with a message similar to the one posted in the question.

The fix this issue, when switching projects, the first command issued consists of switching to the right node version. `nvm use` will be enough on any project having `.nvmrc`.

StackOverflow already has answers on ["How to install nvm"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71864953/132610) - and ["How to use .nvmrc"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57839539/132610)

Answer (score 0):

**This solved if for me:**

1. Downgraded to the latest version of Node v12.
2. Delete the node_modules folder, and reinstall them.

**Note:**
I'm using Angular v8, so I checked their [update site](https://update.angular.io/?v=6.0-8.0) to see when upgrading to Angular 8 what Node version is recommended, and it's Node v10, and since Node should be backwards compatible I just went down from Node v13 to Node v12.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and ran `npm audit fix` like four times, sometimes with the `--force` flag and that fixed it for me after none of the other answers here worked.