# How to install NVM on a Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, nvm

I am trying to install NVM on my Mac using the following command:

```bash
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
```

However, I am getting an error with the message: ***"syntax error near unexpected `("***. More details on the error log are provided down below. What am I doing wrong?

```
VFZ:repo2022 john$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4934  100  4934    0     0    686      0  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:--   686
bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: line 1: `<!-- Copyright (C) 2016 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved. -->'
VFZ:repo2022 john$
```

System - MAC

Answer (score 8):

There is a solution using 'Rosetta 2'
From terminal:

```
$ sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Install NVM using curl (found on the NVM Readme)

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
```

Then install whatever Node version (example installs latest)

```
$ nvm install node
```

Check Node Version

```
$ node -v
```

Source: https://dev.to/httpjunkie/setup-node-version-manager-nvm-on-mac-m1-7kl

Comment: Does not work anymore in 2024 `zsh: command not found: nvm`

Answer (score 1):

Homebrew (`brew`) makes it easy to install and manage versions of `nvm`.
If you have homebrew already available, please run `brew install nvm`. And you will be all set.

Answer (score 1):

If curl doesn't work you can use wget, for which you should have wget installed which you can install using homebrew.

`brew install wget`

Then run the following command,

`wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash` .

The installer will automatically update the profiles files but if it doesn't you can update it manually like this.

First identify which shell is it that you are using:

`echo $0`

if its zsh, update the `~/.zprofile` file.
if its bash, update the `~/.bash_profile` file
with the following lines

`export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"`

After that you can run `source ~/.bashrc` in case of bash, or run `source ~/.zprofile` in case of bash, you can then use NVM.