# Gatsby 3.X + Netlify

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby, netlify

I recently upgraded my Gatsby project from 2.X to 3.X, but I'm having some deployment issues with Netlify. Where is this issue coming from and how can I update Node.js in Netlify?

**Netlify Console:**

```js
5:24:48 PM: error Gatsby requires Node.js 12.13.0 or higher (you have v10.24.0).
5:24:48 PM: Upgrade Node to the latest stable release: https://gatsby.dev/upgrading-node-js
```

[image]

**macOS Terminal:**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue when updating an existing Netlify site from Gatsby 2 to 3. The [Netlify Forum](https://answers.netlify.com/t/node-js-version-on-netlify-outdated/34768) suggests simply adding an environment variable to that Netlify site:

`NODE_VERSION=12`

I don't love this solution since deploying a Gatsby 3 project has no issues when deployed to a freshly created Netlify site, but it did get me going again.

Comment: Tried this and saw `Downloading and installing node v12.22.2...` in the build and it was successful. Thanks 

Answer (score -1):

[Try this :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110542/how-to-write-a-nvmrc-file-which-automatically-change-node-version)

In the root of your repository : `node -v > .nvmrc`
(I suppose `nvm` is installed)

This creates a file with the Node version that should be used for build. If your repository's Node version is actually > 12.13.0, should be fine then.

You might need to run `nvm use` afterwards as mentioned in the linked thread.