# "compiled against a different Node.js version using" only when using node in launch.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

I have `test.js`:

```js
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');

console.log('hi');
```

`launch.json`

```json
...
    {
      "name": "test script",

      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "node",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.js",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
...
```

When I run `test script` in the VSCode debugger I get

```bash
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144
  return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
                 ^

Error: The module '/Users/me/Documents/gift_registry_business_idea/backend/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dashiellbarkhuss/Documents/gift_registry_business_idea/backend/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

However, `test.js` **works fine** if I run `node test.js` in the terminal or if I run this in `launch.json`, changing **node** to **nodemon**

```json
...
    {
      "name": "test script",

      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.js",
      "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
...
```

Deleting node_modules and runing `npm rebuild` or `npm install` didn't work.

Comment: What's `launch.json` used by? Because that's not a standard Node/NPM thing.

Comment: from https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1942 possibly caused by installing `node-canvas` with a different version of nodeJS than you try to run `node-canvas` with. from https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1879 try deleting `node-canvas`'s folder in `node_modules` and then running `npm install` again. Does that answer your question / solve your problem? (found those by googling "`"canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "was compiled against a different Node.js version using"`")

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's a VSCode thing

Comment: @user canvas was fine, I think it was the node version used by launch.json. It didn't match the nvm version. adding `"runtimeVersion": "16.17.1"` worked

Answer (score 0):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_multi-version-support

> Multi version support
> If you are using 'nvm' (or 'nvm-windows') to manage your Node.js versions, >it is possible to specify a runtimeVersion attribute in a launch >configuration for selecting a specific version of Node.js:
>
> ```
> {
>  "type": "node",
>  "request": "launch",
>  "name": "Launch test",
>  "runtimeVersion": "14",
>  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test.js"
> }
> ```

I added the `runtimeVersion to match my environment, and it worked. But I'd like to know if there's a way to set the node version without having to set it individually on each launch configuration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57110542/11107541