# Why is nvm switching versions automatically when I change directory to "node_modules" in my project? There is no '.nvmrc' file in the directory

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nvm

See this screen recording:

[image]

After running `npm install` and then changing directories to the `node_modules` folder, `nvm` is automatically switching me to the default version of node on my system (v20.5.1). Why is this happening? There is no `.nvmrc` file in the directory. Is this just the default behavior of `nvm`?

I was expecting my `nvm use 18` statement to stick.

If anyone can shed some light on why this is happening, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was an alias and corresponding function in `.bashrc`:

```bash
cdnvm() {
    command cd "$@" || return $?
    nvm_path=$(nvm_find_up .nvmrc | tr -d '\n')

    # If there are no .nvmrc file, use the default nvm version
    if [[ ! $nvm_path = *[^[:space:]]* ]]; then

        declare default_version;
        default_version=$(nvm version default);

        # If there is no default version, set it to `node`
        # This will use the latest version on your machine
        if [[ $default_version == "N/A" ]]; then
            nvm alias default node;
            default_version=$(nvm version default);
        fi

        # If the current version is not the default version, set it to use the default version
        if [[ $(nvm current) != "$default_version" ]]; then
            nvm use default;
        fi

    elif [[ -s $nvm_path/.nvmrc && -r $nvm_path/.nvmrc ]]; then
        declare nvm_version
        nvm_version=$(<"$nvm_path"/.nvmrc)

        declare locally_resolved_nvm_version
        # `nvm ls` will check all locally-available versions
        # If there are multiple matching versions, take the latest one
        # Remove the `->` and `*` characters and spaces
        # `locally_resolved_nvm_version` will be `N/A` if no local versions are found
        locally_resolved_nvm_version=$(nvm ls --no-colors "$nvm_version" | tail -1 | tr -d '\->*' | tr -d '[:space:]')

        # If it is not already installed, install it
        # `nvm install` will implicitly use the newly-installed version
        if [[ "$locally_resolved_nvm_version" == "N/A" ]]; then
            nvm install "$nvm_version";
        elif [[ $(nvm current) != "$locally_resolved_nvm_version" ]]; then
            nvm use "$nvm_version";
        fi
    fi
}

alias cd='cdnvm'
cdnvm "$PWD" || exit
```

I think I must have added it when I installed NVM and forgot about it. The function and alias comes from the NVM README:

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#deeper-shell-integration

Deleting the function and alias solved the issue.

Comment: Did you copy the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110542/how-to-write-a-nvmrc-file-which-automatically-change-node-version/57881919#57881919?

Comment: @M-- I think I copied it from the nvm README: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#deeper-shell-integration

Comment: OK, please include that link in the body of your answer for proper attribution. It's been picked up by Gutenberg as plagiarism; see here https://copypastor.sobotics.org/posts/3705 Cheers.